# What are processes that take no input and produce no output?

Tags: process, operating-system

I am doing some old review questions from my Operating Systems class and can't seem to find the answer to this anywhere. I was thinking that one of such processes might be a Zombie process. Thanks in advance!

All the processes that are typically in a computer system have three phases: input, processing, and output. Yet, there are some processes that cannot take any input and do not produce any output. Can you give the generic name of those processes and give an example of two of them? How can we communicate with such processes because there is no input or output?

Comment: Processes? I may be blatantly wrong here but you can think of functions and algorithms having input, processing, and output, but a "typical" process may consist of many of these input-processing-output phases. Did you read this somewhere? If possible, could you quote that source literally, please? Anyway, to answer your question, it is pretty much dependent on what you mean by "no input [...] no output": does `argc`/`argv`/`envp`/whatever count as input? If yes, it's implementation-defined. Otherwise, `shutdown`, `ifconfig`, and `arp` come to my mind spontaneously. Narrow that down a bit.

Comment: This is what my OS professor asked as an old test question. The professor has been teaching OS for years.  I'm not sure he is wrong about this.  Why did I receive a down vote?  Alright, I'll look into those.

Comment: Oops, sorry, `ifconfig` and `arp` produce output, beg your pardon. `shutdown` is the only one I can think of if you don't count shutting down the computer as an output... BTW, I didn't downvote, I don't see the reason either. Maybe due to lack of clarity.

Comment: Are you including deliberately pointless and/or faulty processes?

Comment: A process with one thread on an infinite sleep, paged out completely except for a couple kernel structs that are no longer accessed, seems like it could be no input and no output.

Comment: I would say it would include all processes you would find on a computer system, no matter the function.  Thanks @cad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many operating systems have a NULL process executes when no other process is executable. That process does nothing. It cannot do input/output because it needs to be executable all the time.